# SQLite: table [name_table] has no column named [name_column]

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, syntax-error, sql-insert

I'm working with sqlite in android and I've got this error everytime I add a new item into the database. I don't see any errors, I don't understand what is happening.

Database class:

```
public class Database {

    public static final String KEY_SERIE_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_SERIE_PORTADA = "portada";
    public static final String KEY_SERIE_TITULO = "titulo";
    public static final String KEY_SERIE_AÑO = "año";
    public static final String KEY_SERIE_GENERO = "genero";
    public static final String KEY_SERIE_DESCRIPCION = "descripcion";
    public static final String KEY_SERIE_TEMPORADAS = "temporadas";


    private final Context mContext;

    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    private static final String SERIES_TABLE = "SeriesTable";


    private static final String CREATE_SERIES_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + SERIES_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_SERIE_ID + " LONG PRIMARY KEY, "
                    + KEY_SERIE_PORTADA + " BLOB NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_SERIE_TITULO + "TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_SERIE_AÑO + "INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_SERIE_GENERO + "TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_SERIE_DESCRIPCION + "TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_SERIE_TEMPORADAS + "INTEGER NOT NULL"
                    + ")";


    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_SERIES_TABLE);
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SERIES_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public void Reset() {
        mDbHelper.onUpgrade(this.mDb, 1, 1);
    }

    public Database(Context ctx) {
        mContext = ctx;
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
    }

    public Database open() throws SQLException {
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public void insertSerie(Serie serie) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_SERIE_ID, serie.getId());
        cv.put(KEY_SERIE_PORTADA, serie.getPortada());
        cv.put(KEY_SERIE_TITULO, serie.getTitulo());
        cv.put(KEY_SERIE_AÑO, serie.getAño());
        cv.put(KEY_SERIE_GENERO, serie.getGenero());
        cv.put(KEY_SERIE_DESCRIPCION, serie.getDescripcion());
        cv.put(KEY_SERIE_TEMPORADAS, serie.getTemporadas());
        mDb.insert(SERIES_TABLE, null, cv);
    }
```

The error message is:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table SeriesTable has no column named descripcion
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting descripcion=asdasd temporadas=2 genero=Acción titulo=asdasd id=1538229993236 portada=[B@bfa8a8f año=1980
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table SeriesTable has no column named descripcion (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO SeriesTable(descripcion,temporadas,genero,titulo,id,portada,año) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1562)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
        at marc.borruey.filmmanager.database.Database.insertSerie(Database.java:162)
        at marc.borruey.filmmanager.AddShow$2.onClick(AddShow.java:99)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

What could be the problem? I don't know if this is something, but I've noticed that the order of the columns in the log error (INSERT INTO SeriesTable(descripcion,temporadas,genero,titulo,id,portada,año) ) it's not the same order of my Series constructor:

Class Serie:

```
public Serie(Long id, byte[] portada, String titulo, int año, String genero, String descripcion, int temporadas) {
    super(id, portada, titulo, año, genero, descripcion);
    this.temporadas = temporadas;
}
```

I don't know if this is normal or not. I'm new in sqlite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing spaces between the column names and their types in several places:

```
private static final String CREATE_SERIES_TABLE =
    "CREATE TABLE " + SERIES_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_SERIE_ID + " LONG PRIMARY KEY, "
            + KEY_SERIE_PORTADA + " BLOB NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_SERIE_TITULO + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
              // Here ------------^
            + KEY_SERIE_AÑO + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
              // Here ---------^
            + KEY_SERIE_GENERO + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
              // Here ------------^
            + KEY_SERIE_DESCRIPCION + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
              // Here -----------------^
            + KEY_SERIE_TEMPORADAS + " INTEGER NOT NULL"
              // Here ----------------^
            + ")";
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much sir!